# ngMessage validation on checkboxes undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
 <label for="over_13">
    <input type="checkbox" name="over_13" ng-model="user.over_13" ng-required="user.over_13==true">
    <span>I'm over 13</span>
 </label>

    <ng-messages class="modal-error" for="registerForm.over_13.$error" ng-show="registerForm.$submitted" class="error-message">
        <ng-message when="required">Are you over 13 years old?</ng-message>
    </ng-messages>
```

but when I run it I get the follow in the HTML of the page via chrome inspect

```
<ng-messages class="modal-error ng-inactive" for="registerForm.over_13.$error" ng-show="registerForm.$submitted">
        <!-- ngMessage: undefined -->
    </ng-messages>
```

Am I missing something?

Also using `required` instead of ng-required produced the same error.

```
 <label for="over_13">
    <input type="checkbox" name="over_13" ng-model="user.over_13" required>
    <span>I'm over 13</span>
 </label>
```

Comment: Maybe you should remove the `ng-required="user.over_13==true"` ? That says make this checkbox required if the user is over 13. So if the checkbook is not checked, then it is not required. Replace it w/the regular `required` attribute instead?

Comment: required attribute doesn't work either. Sorry I should of mentioned that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing `for`, it'll need an element with same `id`. So it won't work with `name` and definitely not with `$error`.

Why you have `ng-show` condition for your `ng-message` as `ng-show="registerForm.$submitted"` as you should not be able to submit the form since checkbox is `required`. Also, you have declared `class` attribute twice.

Confusing but this should work.

```
<form name="registerForm">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="over_13" ng-model="user.over_13" required>
    <span>I'm over 13</span>
  </label>

  <ng-messages ng-show="registerForm.over_13.$invalid">
    <ng-message when="required">Are you over 13 years old?</ng-message>
  </ng-messages>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mikki Viitala is wrong about $submitted. Per the [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) for `$submitted`:

> True if user has submitted the form even if its invalid.

If you add a function to `ng-submit` on the `<form>`, even if you abort the action because (e.g.) `$scope.formName.$valid` is false:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
   if (!$scope.formName.$valid) {
      // $scope.formName.$submitted === true
      return;
   }
};
```

`$submitted` is still true (and the `<form>` will still get the `.ng-submitted` class). It's entirely possible to have a `<form>` where the CSS selector `form.ng-pristine.ng-submitted` matches (i.e. the user entered nothing, but clicked the submit button).

Also, Mikki Viitala is wrong about the `for` attribute. The `for` on the `<label>` links the `<label>` to an input field via either the `name` or `id` value on the input field (could be `<input>`, `<select>`, etc). That's just part of the HTML spec. It's mostly for purposes like (e.g.) when you click on the label the linked field comes gains focus.

But the `for` attribute on `<ng-messaages>` is different. It's an expression that evaluates to an object (or dict/associative array/whatever if you prefer). Then each of the `when="blah"` attributes on the `<ng-message>` elements control when to show that particular message.

`$scope.formName.fieldName.$error` returns an object where each attribute corresponds to a type of validation. For example, if a field is marked as required, `$scope.formName.fieldName.$error.required` is a boolean that is true if the field has a value, and false if it doesn't.

`<ng-messages>` goes through all of the `<ng-message>` elements under it in order, using `when="string"` or (`when="string1, string2"`) to pull attributes from the result of `when="object"` until one of them is true, then it displays that one (i.e. the order of the `<ng-message>` elements can matter depending on what you want to acheive).

This is all in the [AngularJS ngMessage docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages).

Comment: It's Mikko, not Mikki :) Anyway, per HTML5 W3C Recommendation 28 October 2014 @ https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for `The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the same Document as the label element.`

Comment: And second, you can add `ng-submit` to form but I really don't see the point checking validity in the controller and using that to control logic in the template when default should be; you can not submit the form if it's in invalid state. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: That reference to the "for" attribute is listed under the `<label>` element in the HTML5 docs. A `<ng-messages for="">` is not a `<label>` element. In this context, the `<label>` element is the "caption" that your quote is referring to. It's for linking a `<label>` to a `<input>` or `<select>`. (Sorry for the typo in the name though)

Comment: Usage with outside of `<label>` is "undefined" as opposed to "banned."

Comment: Ah, you are right. Just read my old answer again. I was talking about the label and jumped into ng-messages. Didnt know about that the time. I rephrase my answer.

Comment: But no, label for links to id, not name :-)